# Can I hide any contact from my messenger app in the iOS Share Sheet (Swift 5)

Tags: ios, swift, ios-sharesheet

I work on some messenger app and I seeking a way to hide blocked contact (it was blocked in my app) in the iOS Share Sheet. Can I do it in my code?

How does iOS Share Sheet work? How does it get contacts from any app?
[image: exemple]

Comment: May be this can help you: [link](https://www.idownloadblog.com/2020/07/17/disable-ios-share-sheet-contacts-tutorial/)

Comment: Thx, but I wand to hide contact from side of my app

Comment: `activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = [UIActivity.ActivityType(rawValue: "com.apple.MobileSMS")]` try this.

Comment: this solution can hide my app on the Share Sheet but I want to hide any contact from my app

Comment: You can still take a look at excluding certain activity types. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiactivity/activitytype